# nginx : how redirect server side application access to correct domain ( multiple domains on same vps )

Tags: nginx, redirect, port

I'm facing an issue on my nginx configuration :

---

**Context:**

- I have a VPS, and multiple domains on it.
- I host **2** web applications on it.
- I use let's encrypt through certbot to handle https.

Each web app is composed of :

- a static build for front-end served on one domain ( http redirects to https )
- a https served node.js backend ( port :5000/graphql for app1 and :5001/graphql for app2 )

I can access to each backend if I specify the port, using any of the domain I have :

- https//domain1:5000/graphql is ok ( :5000 is for the backend of app1 served on domain1 )
- https//domain2:5000/graphql is also ok ( complaining not secure, since :5000 is for app1 )

---

**My question:**

How can I configure properly nginx to redirect all request to :5000 to https://domain1:5000 and all request on :5001 to https://domain2:5001 ? ( and doing the same for the other port)

---

**My nginx conf**

( both apps have same config expect for the domain and the port )

```
server {
        server_name domain1.com www.domain1.com;
        root /path/to/client/build
        index index.html;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/domain1.com.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/domain1.com.error.log;

        location / {
                try_files $uri /index.html;
        }
        location /graphql {
                proxy_pass https://localhost:5000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = www.domain1.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = domain1.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        server_name domain1.com www.domain1.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this (**not tested** - please experiment with the `proxy_ssl_xxx` directives from [the manual](http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_proxy_module.html#proxy_ssl)):

```
server {
        server_name .domain1.com;
        root /path/to/client/build
        index index.html;

        location / {
                try_files $uri /index.html;
        }
        location /graphql {
                proxy_pass https://localhost:5000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }


    listen 443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
        server_name .domain2.com;
        root /path/to/client/build
        index index.html;

        location / {
                try_files $uri /index.html;
        }
        location /graphql {
                proxy_pass https://localhost:5001;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }


    listen 443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain2.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    server_name .domain1.com .domain2.com;
    listen 80;
    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
  server_name .domain1.com;
  listen 5000 ssl;

  location / {
                proxy_pass https://localhost:5000/;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}

server {
  server_name .domain2.com;
  listen 5001 ssl;

  location / {
                proxy_pass https://localhost:5001/;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your try. 

The solution is not working, as I cannot restart ngnix after I change my conf with this informations.

`Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details. failed!`

Comment: Were not you curious to see what the actual culprit was ? Why did not you execute `journalctl -xe` command as the message suggests ? Perhaps your nginX is older and does not support HTTP/2 ? Or maybe there is some syntax error in the config ? I did not actually test this config - just giving you ideas where to continue your troubleshooting. Do not expect that you will just copy/paste and it will solve your problem at zero time and with no efforts ....